# Detecting shapes enclosed by patterns in OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, computer-vision

So, lets say I have a multitude of images that contain a multitude of shapes. In these images there may be shapes inside shapes, and there are two types of shapes. There are shapes with a pattern (like hash marks or diagonal lines), and there are shapes that don't have a pattern inside them.

Such an image could like like this:
[image: Rectangular Shapes]
Let's say I want to only detect shapes that have a pattern in side of them, like this:

[image: Same Image with a shape highlighted purple]

And once I have detected the shape, I want to output a file that looks like this:
[image: Only the shape highlighted above]

My original solution was to convolve the image with the a 3 3 identity matrix, blur the image, and then try to detect blobs from the blurred image.
This doesn't work very consistently, and will not work at all in my images that have a more difficult pattern (like a crosshatch)

Does anybody know of any good strategies I could use to generate that output file?

This is a follow up on a question I asked a while ago, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35367932/extracting-shapes-that-meet-a-certain-criteria-from-an-image)
The answer I received last time was fantastic for the examples I posted, but I'd like to move to opencv, and the answer from last time fails for things like the example above, due to the nested shapes.

As an aside, is there a more proper way for me to ask this question? It's very similar to my previous question, but slightly different. I'm posting this on the bases that it's different enough from my last question.

Comment: Apply a brusher that respect slim lines, and then go with the answer to your previous question.

Comment: I'd suggest that you try to provide at least some initial code. The Python OpenCV tutorial on hierarchical contours might be a starting point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have not provided code for your question, I'll also provide the answer without code:

1. Detect the lines of the diagonal pattern by using a hough transformation
2. Determine the end points of the diagonal pattern
3. For each contour, check whether the end points of the diagonal pattern lie on the contour (using Shapely)
4. For each contour which intersects with end points of the diagonal pattern, fill it
5. For each contour which intersects with end points of the diagonal pattern, determine all inner contours (children) using contour hierarchy and deselect the areas belonging to these inner contours.

Comment: Thanks!
I'm super new to computer vision, so a high level answer like this is what I was looking for :)
I'll accept this answer after I give these steps a try (if I have any questions, i'll be sure to post code and let you know!)

Comment: I was able to detect my shapes after looking up  the tools you mentioned in your answer, thank you! :)